# Install Discourse (a docker image) on Openshift Online

Tags: docker, openshift, discourse

I have an open shift online server and I want to install [Discourse](http://discourse.org)

How would I go about installing this on my open shift online? I've tried looking up how to install docker on to open shift online, but I haven't had any luck for a good tutorial

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Docker is not supported on the current (v2) version of OpenShift Online.  If you would like to use Docker with OpenShift, I would suggest that you look into OpenShift Origin (which is v3) at https://www.openshift.org

Comment: Is there a major difference in cost?

Comment: You would have to run OpenShift Origin yourself on your own hardware.

Comment: Do you think it would be better to run Origin on AWS instead of just buying Online as a PAAS? (If it's for a school's programming classes, which does a lot of small projects in a bunch of different languages for a variety of different purposes)

Comment: What we need is a YAML/JSON definition for a working Discourse.